# How to make a PHP program work via proxies?

Tags: php, proxy

I have never delt with proxies but now I have to. The program is a PHP parser that scraps several websites to retrieve need info. I just need to know how PHP programs work via proxies... how to make them work via proxies.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: These questions should be naturally banned from SO

Comment: These questions are technically alright ;)

Comment: Then you might want to search proxyfire.net for fresh proxies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use curl with `CURLOPT_PROXY` Option.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/stream_context_create

For example:

```
<?php
    $opts = array ( 'http' => array ( 'proxy' => 'tcp://proxy:8080', 'request_fulluri' => true ) ) ;
    $context = stream_context_create ( $opts ) ;
    $f = file_get_contents ( 'http://yoururl/', false, $context ) ;
```